# UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net, webforms

I encounter with the below issues:

- I got this type of error when I run my Web Form:

  > "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)."
- I found that I should add the following lines in the `web.config` file, but I get another error:

  > "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
  > The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."

My web.config file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>


</configuration>
```

The lines that I think I should add:

```js
<appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>
```

Comment: Please try to add `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>` to config as well as `<appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>`.

Comment: This is working @LopDev . Thanks
`<appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
 </appSettings>`